# Extension class giving error as Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: controller-extension

I have written extension class for a page. Class is giving

> error as "Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect
>   signature: ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameters() at line 8 column 17".

```
public class TeamMemberExtension {

    Public Team_Member__c memberObj{get;set;}
    string memberId;

    public TeamMemberExtension(ApexPages.StandardController Controller)
    {
       memberId=ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameters().get('id'); 
       if(memberId!=null && memberId!='')
       {
        memberObj = (Team_Member__c)Controller.getRecord(); 
        }
       else
       {
         memberObj = new Team_Member__c();
         }
    } 

    public PageReference save(){
     if(memberId!=null && memberId!='')
            update memberObj;
     else
            insert memberObj;
     return null;     
    }    

    public PageReference cancel()
    {
        return null;
    }

   /* public PageReference saveandnew()
    {
        if(memberId!=null && memberId!='')
            update memberObj;
     else
            insert memberObj;
     return page.TeamMember_New; 
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameters().get('id')
```

to

```
ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id')
```

Refer documentation:

1. [getParameters()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm)
2. [ApexPages Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_ApexPages_methods.htm)

Comment: I think that's perhaps not the most logical document to link to. [`ApexPages`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_ApexPages_methods.htm) seems more apropos?